# Launch JavaScript and new page at same time

Tags: javascript

When a user clicks on a hyperlink I would like to launch a JavaScript function and also launch a page in a new window.  My preference if possible is to use HTML for the new page in case the person lacks JavaScript as fallback.

The following code launches page but not JavaScript.

```
<a href ="http://www.google.com" target ="_blank" onclick="JavaScript:loadText()">click</a>
```

Can someone recommend correct way to so this.  Thx

Comment: How about `<a href ="http://www.google.com" target = "_blank" onclick="loadText()">click</a>`. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Sorry that was typo.  Google loads but not JavaScript.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TSkZM/

Comment: @j08691, what kind of magic do you use? Did exactly same thing and it wasn't even thinking about running my JS func. (removed "javascript:" and added some small alert function...)

Comment: looks like the problem is in your javascript rather than the html code

Comment: Copying jsfiddle did the trick...I must have had a typo somewhere.. Now working. Thank you!